# "Error setting operation panel" jconsole in a

Tags: java, runtime-error, jconsole

When I connect to JConsole I get the following error message in a pop op box.

`Error setting operation panel`: and here is one of my class which is a POJO.
I do not know how this POJO can cause this error, and what should I do to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, switch to VisualVM (jvisualvm) being part of Java since 1.6 (correct if wrong). In addition, install plugin "MBeans" to get "jconsole" functionality.

Faced same problem as you with plain Pojo classes exposed as MBeans via Spring.

After having switched to VisualVM/MBeans I have not seen this problem any longer. Besides, VisualVM provides you further insights of your running JVM and appears to be extensible via plugins.